# How to define in access If [field1] ="window", [field2]="door", [field3] ="wall" THEN [field4] = "building"

Tags: ms-access

How to define in access If [field1] ="window", [field2]="door", [field3] ="wall" THEN [field4] = "Building"

Comment: In what context? SQL query? VBA code? Be specific.

Comment: just a query, i want to update [field4]

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the query designer in Access? It's a good way to learn how queries get constructed if you're new to that sort of thing. Have a look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/training/queries-i-get-started-with-queries-RZ010359093.aspx) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/microsoft-access-for-beginners-part-iii-writing-the-queries-HA010247313.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a new query, but instead of adding one or more tables to the designer, cancel the table picker before right clicking inside the designer and choosing 'SQL View' (alternatively, choose that option from the 'views' dropdown menu found on the far left of the ribbon or toolbar).

2) Add the following SQL code (assuming I've understood your pseudo-code correctly):

```
UPDATE MyTableName SET Field4 = 'Building'
WHERE (Field1 = 'Window') And (Field2 = 'door') And (Field3 = 'wall');
```

3) Choose Run from the ribbon or toolbar (it has an exclamation mark icon).

You can also do this using the designer, though personally I find writing the SQL code directly more convenient.

*Update, in light of the comment:* to assign `Field4` one way or another depending on a certain condition, you can use `IIf`:

```
UPDATE MyTableName
SET Field4 = IIf(Field3 Is Null, 'Apartment', 'Building')
WHERE (Field1 = 'Window') And (Field2 = 'door') And ((Field3 Is Null) Or (Field3 = 'wall'))
```

Comment: now 1 more help please how can i add this                       UPDATE MyTableName SET Field4 = 'Building'
WHERE (Field1 = 'Window') And (Field2 = 'door') And (Field3 = 'wall') ELSE                                                        UPDATE MyTableName SET Field4 = 'Apartment'
WHERE (Field1 = 'Window') And (Field2 = 'door') And (Field3 = 'NULL');

Comment: @EdwardKryez - see my updated answer (I assume by 'NULL' you meant an actual null rather than the string 'NULL').

Comment: Actually i meant NULL string or NO

Comment: @EdwardKryez - hmm, not sure what you mean by a 'NULL string' - a null in both Access SQL and VBA is different from a string (an empty string isn't a null in other words). This is part of the reason it's always a good idea to set text fields' AllowZeroLength property to False (see http://allenbrowne.com/bug-09.html).

Comment: No worries it works (Field3 = 'NULL') thnx, i marked as answered and solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTableName SET Field4 = 'Building'
WHERE (Field1 = 'Window') And (Field2 = 'door') And ((Field3 Is Null) And (Field3 = 'wall'));
```